# Date format (Java-like) "10/28/1979 12:00 AM" convert to date

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have some data as csv with dates this format:

```
10/28/1979 12:00 AM
9/5/1952 12:00 AM
8/18/1981 12:00 AM
1/1/1971 12:00 AM
```

I can load them to a MySQL/PostgreSQL table as they are but for compatibility I would like to convert them to a more usable format like "yyyy-mm-dd". Tried many formats (nothing usefull on the internet). Eg. MySQL:

```
mysql> select DATE_FORMAT('5/1/2018 12:00 AM', '%Y-%m-%d');
+---------------------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT('5/1/2018 12:00 AM', '%Y-%m-%d') |
+---------------------------------------------+
| NULL                                        |
+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Any idea? Or should I code a function to do it and reinvent the wheel?

Comment: If the format is consistent a regex could be used.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I think there is a way to format it more safely but can't really find it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't convert them to any "format"; it is best to store them as `DATE`s.

You should be able to use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert, as them as long as the format used in the csv is consistent.

Comment: And what format are they? '%m/%d/%y %r %p' or smth?

Comment: Found it: `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('10/28/1979 12:00 AM','%m/%d/%Y');`